# Calling function in WPF from silverlight inside web browser control

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, silverlight

I have a WPF application with a web browser control inside which is a silveriight application. Earlier, I have been able to call functions from WPF application to sliverlight application using HTML bridge.

Now, I have to do the opposite to this i.e. I have to call a function inside the WPF application from silverlight.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the property as shown below:

**C# part :**

```
webBrowserControlName.ObjectForScripting = new ScriptInterface();
```

where ScriptInterface is as follows

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public class ScriptInterface
{

    public void CSharpMethod(string data)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(data);
    }
}
```

**HTML part**

in the page that you load in the web browser control do the following :

```
window.External.CSharpMethod('from html page to WPF');
```